# FATAL EXCEPTION: main error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently updated the code and ran just to see this error where the app is starting and closing very next second.
Previous build was running correctly I am experiencing the issue after the update.

> 08-16 16:23:29.883 13995-13995/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.hemanth.anew, PID: 13995
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
>       ComponentInfo{com.example.hemanth.anew/com.example.hemanth.anew.
>       HomeActivity}: 
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object
>   reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null
>   object reference
>           at com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx.getBottomNavigationItemViews(BottomNavigationViewEx.java:569)
>           at com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx.enableAnimation(BottomNavigationViewEx.java:341)
>           at com.example.hemanth.anew.Utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationViewHelper.java:11)
>           at com.example.hemanth.anew.HomeActivity.setupBottomNavigationView(HomeActivity.java:25)
>           at com.example.hemanth.anew.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:19)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

Here's my Home activity code:

```
package com.example.hemanth.anew;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.hemanth.anew.Utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper;
import com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting.");
    setupBottomNavigationView();
}

private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);

  }
}
```

Can someone please help me overcome this error?
Check this BottomNavigationViewHelper.java file:

```
package com.example.hemanth.anew.Utils;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
private static final String TAG = "BottomNavigationViewHel";
@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
public static void setupBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationViewEx 
bottomNavigationViewEx){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
    bottomNavigationViewEx.enableAnimation(false);
    bottomNavigationViewEx.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
    bottomNavigationViewEx.enableShiftingMode(false);
    bottomNavigationViewEx.setTextVisibility(false);
}
}
```

Here's the xml file under the menu section

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavViewBar"
        android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">


    </com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx>

</RelativeLayout>



</merge>
```

Here's activity_home.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">


 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- top toolbar -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_top_tabs"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Middle section (body) -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_center_viewpager"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- bottom navigation -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation_view"/>


</RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's bottom_navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_house"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_house"
    android:title="">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_circle"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_circle"
    android:title="">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_alert"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_alert"
    android:title="">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_android"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
    android:title="">
</item>

</menu>
```

Thanks for all the answers, I found an easy way to tackle the problem in the latest version of android studio. It goes something like this:  add this to BotttomNavigationView.xml file

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

Comment: NullPointerException
in line 
BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);

Comment: Can you show us what your XML layout file looks like? (layout.activity_home)

Comment: I've updated activity_home.xml file please do check

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `NullPointerException`in the `setupBottomNavigationView()`method.
Seems that `bottomNavigationViewEx`is not retrieved.

Comment: I've updated the code for BottomNavigationViewHelper.java. please check

Comment: _I recently updated the code_ -> Have you point out the differences ? Have you check your logs ? Have you done a refresh install ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though this line leads to a `NullPointerException`

```
BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
```

Are you sure `bottomNavigationViewEx` has some valid value?

**EDIT :**

Alright I get what the error is. I tried your code and what I found was that it works perfectly till compileSdkVersion 27. You go any further up, i.e, 28 as of now, and you get an error. This is because the author of the library has built the library for 26 - [check here](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/blob/master/build.gradle). It works on 27 because there wasn't much changes in the code he used for compatibility with 27. But when 28 came out, it wasn't supported. The author has to update his library for SDK 28. You have the following options left:

- Either downgrade your project to use the version by BottomNavigationViewEx (SDK 26 by the codes but SDK 27 should work just fine as well)
- Use some other project other than BottomNavigationViewEx
- Ask the developer of BottomNavigationViewEx to upgrade his project
- Import BottomNavigationViewEx to your project and rewrite problematic methods
  yourself

Comment: Yes, it does. I've updated the code for BottomNavigationViewHelper.java please help.

Comment: Can you post your xml and the menu file specified in your _app:menu_ in the xml? Because I think the error is that the menu file is empty. If you look closely it fails at getBottomNavigationItemViews(), which is a function to return buttons.

Comment: I've updated the menu file, please feel free to check it out.

Comment: you posted the worng xml file. Please post _layout_bottom_navigation_view_

Comment: I've updated the layout_bottom_navigation_view.xml file

Comment: dude I told you to post two file. _bottom_navigation_menu_ and _layout_bottom_navigation_view_. You didn't post _bottom_navigation_menu_. Please post that and we'll be ready to go.

Comment: I just updated bottom_navigation_menu.xml file. PleaseDo help

Comment: @Hemanth Dude, you're not going to get a better answer for this question for the next few months. Accept my answer and close this question.

Answer (score -1):

Check this example:

Step 1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

Step 2. Add the dependency

```
compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.1.2'
```

and for Maven:

Step 13. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
    <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>
```

Step 4. Add the dependency

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.github.ittianyu</groupId>
 <artifactId>BottomNavigationViewEx</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Step 5 . BottomNavigationViewEx.java and copying it to you project。

Step 6 .Adding a custom widget in xml :

```
<com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
 android:id="@+id/bnve"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
 app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_item_color"
 app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_item_color"
 app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_with_view_pager" />
```

Step 7 .Binding view in Activity:

```
BottomNavigationViewEx bnve = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bnve);
```

Step 8 .Disable all animations

```
bnve.enableAnimation(false);
bnve.enableShiftingMode(false);
bnve.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
```

Step 9 .Binding with ViewPager

```
// set adapter
adapter = new VpAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
bind.vp.setAdapter(adapter);

// binding with ViewPager
bind.bnve.setupWithViewPager(bind.vp);
```

Step 10 .ProGuard

If you are using ProGuard you might need to add the following option:

```
-keep public class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationPresenter { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView { *; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an instance of BottomNavigationViewHelper class, if it is not static. As Null pointer Exception initiate from there and it is because, if BottomNavigationViewHelper is not initialized. So, update your code with this and see the error goes.

```
   private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
BottomNavigationViewHelper helper=new BottomNavigationViewHelper();
helper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);

      }
```

Comment: This is incorrect since the method `setupBottomNavigationView` is static and thus can be called from anywhere without object initialization.